# Jquery nested deferred wait for AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, deferred

There's function with deferred who calls another functions with deferred inside:

```
var state = true;

var construct = function() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    dfd
        .then(function() {
            return wakeUp();
        })
        .then(function() {
            return makeCoffee();
        })
        .then(function() {
            return conquireTheWorld();
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log("I'm done");
        });
    dfd.resolve();
}

var wakeUp           = function() {console.log('Woke up');}

var makeCoffee       = function() {console.log('Made some coffee');}

var conquireTheWorld = function() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    if (state) {
        dfd.then(function() {
            return $.when(someAjax('http://babeljs.io')).done(function() {console.log("World done with AJAX");})
        });
    } else {
        dfd.then(function() {
            console.log("World done in a simple way");
        });
    }
    dfd
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Moon done too");
        });
    return dfd.resolve();
}

var someAjax = function(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, in this case it stucks in `conquireTheWorld` function: `.done` part of `$.when` doesn't ran at all, and the other parts was executed after parent one. There's console output:

```
Woke up
Made some coffee
Moon done too //executed before ajax request complete
I'm done //executed before conquerTheWorld function ajax
World done with AJAX
```

How to wait for ajax request? I've tried to remove $.when and process in another .then statement (nothing changed), or return `dfd.promise()` instead of `dfd.resolve()` (it stucks in that function). How to do it in right way?

Comment: whoa. that function can be simplified to `if (state) { return someAjax('http://babeljs.io').done(function () {console.log('ajax whatever');});} else { console.log('whatever'); }` Much overuse of methods.

Comment: @KevinB I have one more action after if/else statement, In that way I should duplicate it or separate it to another function, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a promise :

```
var promise = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
```

A chain can be formed in a single expression as follows :

```
var p = promise.then(fnA).then(fnB).then(fnC);
```

The following is *equivalent* - a chain is formed "by assigment" :

```
var p;
p = promise.then(fnA);
p = p.then(fnB);
p = p.then(fnC);
```

The following is *not equivalent* - `fnA`, `fnB` and `fnC` depend only on `promise`, not on each other.

```
promise.then(fnA);
promise.then(fnB);
promise.then(fnC);
```

The question's `conquireTheWorld()` is written with the "not equivalent" pattern.

`console.log("World done with AJAX")` depends on the initial promise (actually a Deferred) *and* on the AJAX.

Meanwhile, `console.log("Moon done too")` (and `console.log("I'm done")` in the caller) both depend only on the initial promise, and *win the race* over the AJAX-delayed message.

To fix, convert `conquireTheWorld()` to the "equivalent" pattern by making assignments and returning the resultant promise, not the initial promise.

EDIT:

In full :

```
var conquireTheWorld = function() {
    var promise = $.when(); // shorthand way to create a resolved jQuery promise.
    if (state) {
        promise = promise.then(function() {
            return someAjax('http://babeljs.io').then(function() { console.log("World done with AJAX"); });
        });
    } else {
        promise = promise.then(function() {
            console.log("World done in a simple way");
        });
    }
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        console.log("Moon done too");
    });
    return promise;
}
```

There are better ways to achieve the same end, but this is a corrected version of the code in the question.

Comment: `$.Deferred.resolve` is not a function - that error I've got.

Comment: Do you mean $.Deferred().resolve().promise()?
It is not works as expected too. Here's [code](https://pastebin.com/zsK7X4hA) to run, but ajax response still comes after `I'm done` output.

Comment: Yes, `$.Deferred()...`. More typically, people tend to write `$.when()` for a resolved jQuery promise.

Comment: But it's behaviour isnt right, like I wrote above. Is there something not "equivalent" to pattern? I'm working with a single promise I've created in `conquireTheWorld()`, but still got no wait for it.

Comment: You've not done what I said. You need to make assignments.